# Extract Samsung Galaxy S3 keyboard history

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, keyboard

Is there a way to extract a log file containing all keyboard history, and everything that has been typed, from a Samsung Galaxy S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first install a Key Logger on the device (Which will need to be rooted for full functionality) and then you will be able to log all key strokes. There are several apps that offer that. 

P.S Using keyloggers to spy on people is illegal in most countries.

Comment: And does it allow extracting old history (I mean before installation) or just history data after installation?

Comment: no, that is impossible